# Jquery .hover() only working on mouseenter

Tags: jquery, mouse, hover

```
  $(".info-icon").hover(function() {
   var a = this.id;
   var id = a.substring(10);

   var $id = "infobox-"+id;
   $('#'+$id).addClass("hover");
  },
  function() {
   $('#'+$id).removeClass("hover");
  });
```

Anyone seeing the bug?

Thx Sven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that you're trying to add a "hover" class to a *different* element (and then remove it later) based on manipulating the `id` of the element that gets hovered. If so, I would simply do this:

```
(function() {
    $(".info-icon").hover(function() {
        getHoverTarget(this).addClass('hover');
      },
      function() {
        getHoverTarget(this).removeClass('hover');
    });

    function getHoverTarget(element) {
       return $('#infobox-' + element.id.substring(10));
    }
})();
```

This avoids duplicating the logic (duplication = opportunity for messing it up later).

The reason it didn't work the way you wrote it is, as [SLaks points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845855/jquery-hover-only-working-on-mouseenter/4845867#4845867), that your `$id` variable only exists as a local within your first function; your second function doesn't have access to it.

Comment: Is there a reason to have a completely separate function? I'm not saying there isn't, just wondering what your thoughts are.

Comment: @Jared: As I said under the code block: *"Duplication = opportunity for messing it up later"* (e.g., changing one and not the other). :-) Although I admit I can't then immediately justify duplicating the "hover" class... ;-) My original thought avoided that, too, but then looked like overkill.

Comment: You don't think it's simple enough not to have to have extraneous code? I see what you're saying (duplication), but sometimes it's simpler and more straightforward to just do it, instead of making a whole other function. To me, this isn't too different from your comment concerning my use of `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: @Jared: It's totally a judgment call. (That's my upvote on your answer, btw.)

Comment: I appreciate the vote. It can certainly be frustrating to provide a correct answer and not get a vote. I agree; it's just a difference of opinion.

Comment: @Jared: I hear you. :-) It comes out in the wash, though, if you keep contributing.

Comment: To me, it's like drumming; you've got to build chops with practice, but you've got to play with others to know if your time is right. I can keep doing what I do in my own world, assuming I'm right, or expose my thoughts on things to world and see if they withstand the scrutiny. So really, it's just about getting better, at coding and at helping people.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$id` variable is a local variable and only exists in the first callback.

Instead, you should store the id in `$.data`.

Comment: *"Your `$id` variable is a local variable and only exists in the first callback."* **Quite right.** *"Instead, you should store the id in `$.data`."* **No**, there's no need to store (or even use) an `id` at all.

Comment: what would be the advantage.. of storing it in $.data,
Anriëtte Combrink solution is quite .. easy to implement and understand.

Comment: @TJC: That depends on his HTML.

Comment: @SLaks: Ooooh, you're *(partially)* right, he's not using the ID from the actual element at all. Yikes.

Comment: just cutting off some text in front of the id. still don't get the advantage. ;(

Comment: I don't think it needs to be stored. It just needs to be recalculated in each event handler, IMO.

Comment: @Jared: That's my take as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".info-icon").hover(function() {
    $("#infobox-" + this.id.substring(10)).addClass("hover");
},
function() {
    $("#infobox-" + this.id.substring(10)).removeClass("hover");
});
```

Comment: Read more carefully.  That's not what he's doing.

Comment: take a look at the code .. it's not the same element what should get class hover..

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')`?! Or just, you know, `this.id`, avoiding something like four or five function calls and at least one memory allocation. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Put `var $id = "";` outside the function, to make it global, and then in the first callback remove the `var` in front of `$id`, like so `$id = "infobox-"+id;`, this will then store the value in the global variable, `$id`.

Now you can use it in the second callback. Hope this helps.

Comment: **No**.  This will not work, since you're sharing one variable among multiple elements.

Comment: Yeah, but each time you're giving it a new value in the first callback, so I don't see how this will not work. But anywho…life goes on.